# ImportError: No module named main

Tags: python, setuptools, init

I created a program whose setup.py imports setuptools and includes:

```
scripts=['scripts/vibez'],
```

The layout of the directories is as follows

```
projectdirectory
├── __init__.py
├── main.py
└── scripts
    └── vibez
```

The vibez script includes:

```
#!python
import vibez

vibez.start_vibez()
```

The `__init__` script includes:

```
from main import execute
def start_vibez():
    main()
```

The main.py file is annotated at the bottom with:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    execute()
```

I install my application using `python setup.py install.`

I execute `vibez` and this successfully runs the `__init__` file.
It seems as if the `__init__` file's import of main can not be found and I get:

```
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/vibez", line 4, in <module>
    __import__('pkg_resources').run_script('vibez==0.78', 'vibez')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 735, in run_script
    self.require(requires)[0].run_script(script_name, ns)
ImportError: No module named 'main'
```

Why is this occurring?

Comment: change the name of main.py to something else.